# Adding microphone audio to an existing video

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video file which has no audio, I wanted to add audio description using mic while the video is being played i.e. video is being played and I will do a voice  over on it and that get saved a new clip having audio and video.

How to do that with ffmpeg?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend using ffmpeg for this. Rather use a proper nonlinear video editing software that allows you to align video and audio tracks graphically. You're likely going to want to do the recording in smaller chunks of audio and not record everything in one go. You could also use an audio program like Audacity to do the recording offline, and use a video player like VLC to preview the video, then stitch everything together in the end.

That said, you can [record microphone audio](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop) with ffmpeg while doing desktop recordings. The exact command depends on your operating system and method of input. Please refer to the Wiki for that.

If you want to record audio *while* the video is playing, you have to use the original video as input, specify your microphone as a second input source, then output to both a file *and* an `ffplay` process to preview your video.

For example — and this is just a quick solution —, under macOS,  the microphone is selected with `-f avfoundation -i ":0"`. The video is being copied (`-c:v copy`), the audio is encoded with `aac`, and everything is output to both `output.mkv` and a pipe that is fed to `ffplay`.

`ffmpeg -i screencast.mp4 -f avfoundation -i ":0" -c:v copy -c:a aac -f tee -map 0:v -map 1:a "output.mkv|[f=matroska]pipe:" | ffplay -`

Note that this will not be exactly synchronous — you might be seeing the video a little bit too late. Also, your recorded audio will be played back with a bit of delay. Mute your speakers in this case.